# jQuery create int Array from string of numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, split

`<div id="dynamicTable" columns="26,40,41,21,71,39,23,19">`

```
var columns = $('#dynamicTable').attr('columns');
var attributeIds = new Array();
attributeIds = columns.split(',');
```

This creates an array of strings, I need them to be ints. What's the best way to do this?

Comment: changelog answer is no doubt the most elegant possible, but depending on what you need to do with those integers maybe you can do it directly in the `map` function instead of storing the new array in separate variable.

Comment: Thanks! Did the best I could with the amount of information that was given to me :-)

Comment: both changelog and patrick dw work, which is better / faster?

Comment: Both are equally good. Speed isn't an issue here, since it's so fast the difference would be negligible. My only concern in regards to $.parseJSON, as far as I know, is that if you don't include the json2.js library, some older browsers don't implement the native JSON parsing functionality, which has only been around since Dec 2009.

Comment: Nevermind the previous comment. jQuery creates a new function with a body of 'return ' + data, which is essentially the same as eval() when the browser can't do native JSON parsing.

Comment: [In this test](http://jsperf.com/parsejson-vs-map-to-convert-string-to-ints/2), among the browsers I tested, `eval()` is fastest by far, `$.map()` is next, then `$.parseJSON`.

Comment: I added a `while` loop solution to my answer, which seems to give the best overall performance [in this test](http://jsperf.com/parsejson-vs-map-to-convert-string-to-ints/2).

Comment: Kudos on the perf test, btw. Great job. Didn't know about that site.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You could [use `$.parseJSON`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/).

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ULkXy/

```
var columns = $('#dynamicTable').attr('columns');
var attributeIds = $.parseJSON( '[' + columns + ']' );
```

Here's another way using a `while` loop with the unary `+` operator:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ULkXy/1/

```
var columns = $('#dynamicTable').attr('columns');
var attributeIds = columns.split(',');
var len = attributeIds.length;

while( len-- ) {
    attributeIds[len] = +attributeIds[len];
}
```

Comment: Problem with that last solution is that it inverts the order of the ids. What if the ids need to be sent in a specific order?

Comment: @changelog: It doesn't invert the order. It just iterates through the array in reverse. If there are 10 items, index 9 is overwritten by a modified value of index 9. Then 8, 7, 6, etc.. If you click the example link I provided, you'll see that the result in the `alert()` has the same order as that in the `columns` attribute.

Answer (score 7):

```
var columns = $('#dynamicTable').attr('columns'),
    attributeIds = $.map(columns.split(','), function(val, idx) { return parseInt(val, 10) });
```